# I want my onclick listener to pull up phone's contacts

Tags: java, android

So here's what I'm trying to do.

I want to click on a button in my MainActivity and have that pull-up the phones' contacts.  I've already added the READ CONTACTS permission to my manifest.

Here are the relevant sections of code.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 

    getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // the button gets clicked and pulls up user's contacts
            list.findViewById(R.id.list);
        }
    });
}
```

and activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="32sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Pick a Friend to Meet!" />

<ListView 
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run my app,  the main activity appears just fine, the button works (i.e. something happens when I click it), but then the app closes.

This is my first android app, so please be gentle.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace? And why are you calling `findViewById` in your `onClick()` handler ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the list populated with anything?  Can't tell if you have scrubbed or is this is just incomplete code.  Not sure how the button is connected to the list item.  Assuming a list of contacts names and you want one of their phone numbers to pop up when you click the button?  If that is the case then the onClick should figure out which list item is selected.  No need to id the list in the onClick, list is already found.

Also not sure where the number will be displayed.  No view defined for it.  Using Toast?

Great tutorial on ListView here:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

i did it this way:

```
public class ContactFetchActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button contactButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

contactButton.setOnClickListener(l);
}

OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
try{
Uri contactData = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
Cursor contactsCursor = managedQuery(contactData,null, null, null, null);
Log.i("The first one ", ""+ contactsCursor.getCount());
while (contactsCursor.moveToNext()) {
 String id = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
 String name = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
 String hasPhoneNumber = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
 Toast.makeText(ContactFetchActivity.this, Integer.parseInt(hasPhoneNumber) + "", 11).show();
 if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhoneNumber) > 0) {
  Uri myPhoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, id);
  Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
  String phoneNumber = null;
  while (phones.moveToNext()) {
   phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
   Toast.makeText(ContactFetchActivity.this, phoneNumber , 20).show();
  }
  Toast.makeText(ContactFetchActivity.this, id + "-----" + name , 20).show();
 }

}
}catch(Exception ex){
Toast.makeText(ContactFetchActivity.this, "Problem because " + ex.getMessage(), 10).show();
}
//Uri myPerson = ContentUris.withAppendedId(contentUri, id)
}
};
}
```

You can go through this [link](http://hossaindoula.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-get-phone-contacts.html) and [this link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/) for further.

Comment: Did you start a new activity or just insert into the main activity?

Comment: It's my main activity.